# jQuery addClass to label if radio button checked

Tags: jquery

I am unable to add class in label for radio button list, below is html code:

```
<div class="custom-radio">
 <input id="MainContent_rblUserType_2" type="radio" checked="checked" value="3" name="MainContent$rblUserType">
 <label class="" for="MainContent_rblUserType_2">I am buyer</label>
</div>
```

And Jquery that I am trying to add class in label is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($("input.check").is(":checked")){
        $(this).label.addClass("checked");
}
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `.next()`

```
$("input:radio").next('label').addClass("checked");
```

Also, Your input do not have any class with name `check`, so you might want to change it to

```
$("input:radio").is(":checked")
```

You can also do this instead of your if condition -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio:checked").next('label').addClass("checked");
});
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/tLFjA/5/

Comment: can i get pure solution?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `$(this)` is the document, not the input. try instead of this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($("input.check").is(":checked")){
    $(this).label.addClass("checked");
}
});
```

this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.check:checked").next('label').addClass('checked')
});
```

Also, you'll probably need to bind a change event.

```
$('input.check').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.is(:checked) ? $this.next('label').addClass('active') : $this.next('label').removeClass('active') 
})
```

There is also the CSS3 possibility :

```
input.check:checked ~ label{ your styles}
```

The `~` can be + depending on your DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="custom-radio">
   <input id="MainContent_rblUserType_2" class="check" type="radio" checked="checked" value="3" name="MainContent$rblUserType">
   <label class="checkLabel" for="MainContent_rblUserType_2">I am buyer</label>
</div>


$(document).on("click", 'input.check', function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('label.checked').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).next("label.checkLabel").addClass("checked");
  }
});
```

You need to add classes to input and label as shown above.
It binds an event to radio input and when checked, adds class and removes class when radio input is not checked
 
Demo Jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/prem_nagalla1/h7BZa/